# ggplot2, how to use subscript in axis titles?

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

I'm using ggplot2 and GridExtra to combine several graphs and add a common title for x and y axis.

In the y axis, I would like to add the following title : Metal concentration (mg.100g-1 dry weight).
 -1 must appear in superscript.

I tried
`Fig2<-grid.arrange(plot1,plot2, plot3, nrow=1, bottom=" x Title", left=expression(Metal~concentration~(mg.100g^{-1}~dry~weight)))`

but no title appears on the left.

Thank you for your help.

Cécile

Comment: Please provide a simple reproducible example, so it is easier for others to help you.